# How can I save RichTextBox in a file or sql without lost links?

Tags: c#, hyperlink, richtextbox, richtext

I have a Link in Richtextbox  and it works good but if I save that Richtextbox in to a file and then load it that link to be deleted and I just can see the text of that Link

**How can i save richtextbox in a file or sql without lost links?**

for example my Richtextbox have bottom text:

[This is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522758/how-can-i-save-richtextbox-in-a-file-or-sql-without-lost-links)

But after save and load again file I just can see the text:

This is a link

this is my string value that I try to set in my Richtextbox with this code: richTextBox1.Rtf = str;

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs16 Link text\v #Hyperlink text\v0\par
}

Comment: How do you save the content? Can you show us parts of your code? It should work for the RTF file type.

Comment: hello mate, I put a part of code I try to do that. at now could you give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can sove this problem using link label:

Demo for Link label is here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.link.aspx

you have to add linklabel into richtextbox & you have goto this link

Comment: imagine I add a Linklabel control to the RichTextBox. at now how to save it to a file with other texts and images and load them to a RichTextBox again?